# How do I create a grid with divs (or other non-table tags) that has similar properties to a table and without using JS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a grid (of divs?) where the rows each dynamically size to the height of the largest element, and the columns dynamically size to the width of the largest element (within each row / col, so each row and col will be different heights / widths depending on the content). Also, I'd like to optionally horizontally and vertically center the content (no matter what happens to be in there: pics, text, etc.).

In the following example, the table has dynamically sized icons in the first column, each is centered horizontally and vertically, and the width matches the width of the largest icon. The second column contains some text, which is vertically (but not horizontally) centered, and each row is the height of the max content in that row.

[image]

I have been unable to get flexbox to work here, but probably because I'm dumb. I don't want to use JS to re-size things after the fact. The table and contents will be generated dynamically, so I don't want to manually set the height of each row / col.

During my attempts at this, I can get the rows OR the columns to dynamically size based on the content, but can't figure out how to do both at the same time.

**EDIT**: image is somewhat bad example. Imagine the text goes to the end and wraps.

Comment: grid or flexbox, both can work just fine. For the grid I would either use `table-cell` or flexbox to center content vertically and horizontally within the cards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grid layout for this. Define the `grid-template-rows` you want, `grid-template-columns` you want, each using a fractional length of the parents width and/or height, `auto` will make the grid child container size to its elements content.

Then assign the placement of the elements using the `grid-template-areas`. Then on each element assign the `grid-area` property to its own selector.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 0.7fr 1.3fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-template-areas: "star-1 one-line" "star-2 two-line" "arrow three-line";
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.box-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-top: 3px solid black;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}

.star-1 {
  grid-area: star-1;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.one-line {
  grid-area: one-line;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.star-2 {
  grid-area: star-2;
  background-color: pink;
}

.two-line {
  grid-area: two-line;
  background-color: pink;
}

.arrow {
  grid-area: arrow;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-bottom: solid 3px black;
}

.three-line {
  grid-area: three-line;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="star-1 box">star1</div>
  <div class="one-line box-text">one line of content</div>
  <div class="star-2 box">star2</div>
  <div class="two-line box-text">
    <p>two lines of content</p>
    <p>two lines of content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="arrow box">arrow</div>
  <div class="three-line box-text">
    <p>three lines of content</p>
    <p>three lines of content</p>
    <p>three lines of content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### EDIT

The following snippits code will support a dynamicly created flow, elements can be added dynamically to the DOM however you choose: obj, php, whatever, the grid CSS will take over the flow.

You can remove the ***grid-area*** from the children and only one class needed for styling child elements. On the ***container*** change: `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;`. Then add `grid-auto-flow: rows;`, rows will dynamically style as they are added to the DOM. The ICONS parent element will size to their childs content height/width, but rows height will be determined by the *highest* element **icon** or **content**, **content** will fill remaining width of row.

Childs selector, I use a class `box` with `flex-direction: column;` and add props `justify-content` and `align-items` to center content. Add padding as needed. If you want the two rows elements to be styled differently, add a second class to content section and style as you wish.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: rows;
  padding: 1rem; 
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.box:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
  background-color: pink;
}
.box:nth-of-type(3n+3) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.box:first-of-type, .box:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-top: 3px solid black;
}

.box:nth-of-type(even) {
  border-right: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/star-256x256.png" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  <div class="box">one line of content</div>
  <div class="box">
  <img src="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/star-256x256.png" width="50" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>two lines of content</p>
    <p>two lines of content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  <img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/11587-200.png" width="150" height="150">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>three lines of content</p>
    <p>three lines of content</p>
    <p>three lines of content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/11/14/852357_rocket_512x512.png">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>This content will wrap its parent element making its height taller than the proceeding icon row element to its left. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora inci[di]dunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great start. Thanks! The example CSS seems to "know" that there are 2 columns and 3 rows. For the sake of argument, let's say the column count is fixed, but the rows are dynamically generated, so the amount is unknown at the time of writing the CSS. How would you create `grid-template-areas` and `grid-template-rows` properties?

Comment: @user439299 i see, check out my ***edit***, `grid-auto-flow: rows` will do the trick.